# Pass information to a view Controller underneath current view controller for objective c

Tags: objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller

I am presenting a modal view controller on top of my current view controller, and I want to pass information to the view controller underneath (the hidden one) before I dismiss the controller that is covering. I am not looking for specific code so much as strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to create the object as a property in your CurrentViewController and pass that object over to the ModalViewController ( This can be possibly done by creating your own init method ). Your ModalViewController can update this object as and when the User performs an action or whatever you are trying to do. Since this object was created in CurrentViewController , the data will remain valid and accessible from there once the ModalView is dismissed.

Comment: Would an NSMutableDictionary be a good example of an object to use for something like this?

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using an NSMutableDictionary and it worked. And I didn't have to worry about assigning delegates.

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to do this is have the parent view controller (the hidden one) be a delegate of the visible view controller.  The visible view controller calls its delegate to pass information to the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You could adress the view.superview.delegate.. You can always check the classs and check if it will respond to the action your calling.